# Audio file plays over itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I'm building an app with multiple view controllers and I have coded an audio file to play at the start up of the app. That works fine and when I click on the button to view a different screen the audio file still plays without skipping a beat just like it's supposed to but my problem arises when I click on the button to go back to the main screen. When I click to go back to the main screen the audio file plays over itself reminding me of the song Row Row Your Boat. The app is re-reading that code that tells itself to play the audio file thus playing it all over again. My problem is that I can't figure out how to make it not do that. I have coded the app to stop the audio when clicking on the start game button, which is what I want it to do but not until then. I just need help getting the app to not play the audio file over itself when going back to the main screen. The audio file is coded to play infinitely until the "start" button is clicked. If anyone can make since out of what I'm trying to say then please help me code this thing correctly. Thanks to anyone who can make it work right.

Here my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *introMusic = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"invadingForces" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioPlayer0 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:introMusic] error:NULL];
    audioPlayer0.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer0.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer0 play];

}
```

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is an immutable type, sounds like you're getting multiple instances. Where and how are you declaring audioPlayer0 ?

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad  is in the initial viewController.m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code to wrap an **AVAudioPlayer** in a singleton -

**BWBackgroundMusic.h**

```
@interface BWBackgroundMusic : NSObject

// singleton getter
+ (instancetype)sharedMusicPlayer;

/*  public interface required to control the AVAudioPlayer instance is as follows -

    start - plays from start - if playing stops and plays from start
    stop - stops and returns play-head to start regardless of state
    pause - stops and leaves play-head where it is - if already paused or stopped does nothing
    continue - continues playing from where the play-head was left - if playing does nothing

    replace audio track with new file - replaceBackgroundMusicWithFileOfName:
    set background player to nil - destroyBackgroundMusic

    NOTE:- change default track filename in .m #define */

// transport like methods
- (void)startBackgroundMusic;

- (void)stopBackgroundMusic;

- (void)pauseBackgroundMusic;

- (void)continueBackgroundMusic;

// audio source management
- (void)replaceBackgroundMusicWithFileOfName:(NSString*)audioFileName startPlaying:(BOOL)startPlaying;

- (void)destroyBackgroundMusic;

@end
```

**BWBackgroundMusic.m**

```
#import "BWBackgroundMusic.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> // must link to project first

#define DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_AUDIO_FILENAME @"invadingForces.mp3"

@interface BWBackgroundMusic ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusicPlayer;

@end

@implementation BWBackgroundMusic

#pragma mark Singleton getter
+ (instancetype)sharedMusicPlayer {

    static BWBackgroundMusic *musicPlayer = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
        musicPlayer = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    //NSLog(@"sample rate of file is %f",[musicPlayer currentSampleRate]);

    return musicPlayer;
}

#pragma mark Initialiser
- (id)init {
    //NSLog(@"sharedMusicPlayer from BWBackgroundMusic.h init called...");
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // self setup _backgroundMusicPlayer here...
        // configure the audio player
        NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_AUDIO_FILENAME]];
        NSError *error;
        if (_backgroundMusicPlayer == nil) {
            _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:&error];
        }
        if (_backgroundMusicPlayer == nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
        } else {
            [self makePlaybackInfinite];
            [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Selfish methods
- (void)makePlaybackInfinite {
    // access backing ivar directly because this is also called from init method
    if (_backgroundMusicPlayer) {
        _backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)currentSampleRate {
    NSDictionary *settingsDict = [self.backgroundMusicPlayer settings];
    NSNumber *sampleRate = [settingsDict valueForKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    return [sampleRate floatValue];
}

#pragma mark Transport like methods
- (void)startBackgroundMusic {
    // plays from start - if playing stops and plays from start
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlayer.isPlaying) {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];// this is not required as play calls this implicitly if not already prepared
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)stopBackgroundMusic {
    // stops and returns play-head to start regardless of state and prepares to play
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlayer.isPlaying) {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}

- (void)pauseBackgroundMusic {
    // stops and leaves play-head where it is - if already paused or stopped does nothing
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlayer.isPlaying) {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer pause];
    }
}

- (void)continueBackgroundMusic {
    // continues playing from where the play-head was left - if playing does nothing
    if (!self.backgroundMusicPlayer.isPlaying) {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
}

#pragma mark Content management
- (void)replaceBackgroundMusicWithFileOfName:(NSString*)audioFileName startPlaying:(BOOL)startPlaying {
    // construct filepath
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], audioFileName];
    // make a url from the filepath
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    // construct player and prepare
    NSError *error;
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self makePlaybackInfinite];
    // if startplaying then play
    if (startPlaying) {
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)destroyBackgroundMusic {
    // stop playing if playing
    [self stopBackgroundMusic];
    // destroy by setting background player to nil
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = nil;
}

@end
```

To use simply call `[BWBackgroundMusic sharedMusicPlayer];` This will instantiate the singleton if not already instantiated, start the player automatically, and will loop infinitely by default.

Furthermore you can control it from any class that imports BWBackgroundMusic.h

For example to pause the player use

`[[BWBackgroundMusic sharedMusicPlayer] pauseBackgroundMusic];`

Comment: @Bamsworld, I tend to avoid providing complete code in an answer. The OP learns more if you provide an outline of a solution and let them try to implement it. Your solution looks really good, but perhaps TOO thorough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start a sound in a local variable when your view is loaded, start it playing on endless repeat, and then forget about it. Then you close the view controller, leaving the now-forgotten audio player playing. Next time you invoke the view controller, it's `viewDidLoad` method creates another audio player and starts that one playing too, and then forgets about that one. Every time you open a new copy of that view controller, you'll start yet another sound player, adding another voice to your round of "row, row, row your boat."

The naive solution is to put the code that starts the sound player in the app delegate. Set up the `AVAudioPlayer` as a property of you app delegate. Create a startPlaying method and a stopPlaying method. In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, call startPlaying.

It's cleaner app design not to put app functionality in your app delegate, but instead create a singleton to manage sound play. (Search on "iOS singleton design pattern" to learn more.) Create an `appDidLaunch` method in the singleton, and call `appDidLaunch` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to start playing your sound. That way the app delegate doesn't need to have app specific logic in it, but simply calls `appDidLaunch` and goes on it's way.

### EDIT:

If you want to call a method in the app delegate, and your app delegate is declared as:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Then you'd call it from another file like this:

First, import the app delegate's header:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

And the actual code to call your app delegate's stopPlaying method:

```
//Get a pointer to the application object.
UIApplication *theApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

//ask the application object for a pointer to the app delegate, and cast it 
//to our custom "AppDelegate" class. If your app delegate uses a different 
//class name, use that name here instead of "AppDelegate"
AppDelegate *theAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)theApp.delegate;
[theAppDelegate stopPlaying];
```

Comment: Hey Duncan, Thanks for the helpful hint. I tried putting the code in the appDelegate.m file first but I couldn't get my start button on the main viewController to stop the audio from there for some reason so I decided to put it in the main view instead but we know how that worked out. I'm new to coding and I'm having a tough time figuring this out all own my own. What you have described sounds good but I really need someone to show me how to write it so I'll know how to go about it the next time around. If you have time could you help me out with that?

Comment: I won't have time in the foreseeable future. (I'm on-site full time at a client's, and have another <paying> client who I have been putting off.) See my suggestion about adding a startPlaying and stopPlaying method in the app delegate. Then call the stopPlaying method if you need to stop the sound playing. I'll edit my answer to show how to call the method in the app delegate.

Comment: Note that putting this stuff in the app delegate is "quick and dirty". It works, but it is cleaner to use a singleton for this, as mentioned in my answer.